# Chartkick & Rails 3 - set min and max x-axis for time values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chartkick

I have a chart like so:

```
<%= line_chart Click.where(:deal_id => @deal.id).group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

I know we can pass min and max values, but I don't know how to pass time values correctly. I tried doing something like this:

```
<%= line_chart Click.where(:deal_id => @deal.id).group_by_day(:created_at).count, min: Time.now - 5.days, max: Time.now %>
```

This didn't change the axis. I want to have a rolling 5 day chart essentially. How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
line_chart Click.where(:deal_id => @deal.id).group_by_day(:created_at, last: 5).count
```

For more details, see the time range section of the Groupdate documentation: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#time-range

Comment: That did it. My labels are still wrong though. Does adding `discrete: true` allow me to change the axis point labels? Sorry if that's in the documentation, I didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a combination of discrete: true and the Groupdate format option to do this.