# How to make column charts x axis present exactly one week in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick, column-chart

I am using "chartkick" gem for presenting data with the help of column chart.
Shortly, I am doing "ToDo" project and want to show how many tasks have been completed by the user each day of the last week.

However, I want the x axis represent exactly 7 days, even if there are no completed tasks.

A picture of column chart now

[image: 1]

Here is how I make column chart.

```
<%= column_chart @completed_tasks.where("completed_time >= ?", 1.week.ago).group_by_day(:completed_time).count%>
```

And in case if needed, here is how i get `@completed_tasks` variable.

```
@completed_tasks = Task.where(user_id: current_user.id, completed: true)
```

I have been thinking about it for a couple of days, but did not come up to anything, in addition i could not find any ideas on the Internet, so I hope someone here knows how to do it.

Comment: I can't help you with chartkick but in modern versions of Ruby (>= 2.6.0) you can use an [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges) in your query like `where(completed_time: 1.week.ago..)` which helps make the code a little cleaner.

Comment: is there a chance that you might know someone who can help me? This is my final project at uni and the deadline is soon :(

Comment: I'm not certain if this is what you're looking for but you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22930017/3784008) for a possible solution. The person asks *I want to have a rolling 5 day chart* which sounds very similar to this. The person that provided the answer is the author of chartkick. There's additional detail in the [chartkick docs](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#time-range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
<%= column_chart @completed_tasks.group_by_day(:completed_time, last:7).count%>
```

Thanks to @anothermh